# Error in Project Creation with Basic Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in android studio. When I created a new project in it, with Empty activity, it compiles and run without any error. But when I created the project with basic activity, an error occurs. 
MainActivity class and activity_main.xml is not created and there is some error
in Android Manifest.xml.

How can I solve this error ?

I have tried to update the gradle file but error remains there.
[image]

I am using android studio 3.0.1 and gradle version 4.1

Answer (score 0):

If MainActivity class and activity_main.xml aren't created, then you have to create them yourself. Then the problem is solved

Comment: But android studio creates it by itself in empty activity project.

Comment: @SaboorElahi but you've said that they aren't created

Comment: In Basic Activity option, android studio does not create these files, but include them in android Manifest

Comment: @SaboorElahi try to create them yourself

Comment: But the thing which is confusing me is that, if android studio does not create the files then why does it include them in android manifest, and why a new project does not build properly

Comment: @SaboorElahi  I neither know it, maybe you have some problems with SDK